# How to combine MS Access columns with Dapper using VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, dapper

How to combine MS Access columns with Dapper using VB.NET?

Please guide.

```
Private iService As New Itemservice2()
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        DataGridView1.DataSource = iService.Getitem()
    End Sub
Public Function Getitem() As IEnumerable(Of Stocks)
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Stocks"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stocks)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
Public Class Stocks
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Colorcode() As String
    Public Property Size() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
End Class
```

Result from function `Getitem` in datagridview:

| Id | CodeProduct | Colorcode | Size | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KBT 1809 |  | S | 10 |
| 2 | KBE 0927 | BHTF07KP | M | 30 |

Desired result from function `Getitem` in datagridview:

| Id | Combine | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KBT 1809 S | 10 |
| 2 | KBE 0927 BHTF07KP M | 30 |

Comment: You could create a read only property in your stocks class that does all the field concatenation and formatting for you,  then bind that to your data grid view

Comment: @Hursey , `You could create a read only property in your stocks class that does all the field concatenation and formatting for you,` Thank you for your reply. How do I make property read only as you mean please give me a guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My VB is rusty to say the least, but you should be able to declare a readonly property like this:

```vb
Public Class Stocks
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Colorcode() As String
    Public Property Size() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Combine() As String
        Get
            Return String.Concat(CodeProduct, " ", Colorcode, "", Size).Trim()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Then you need to hide the superfluous columns in the grid view.

Comment: your answer is perfect.  But for property `CodeProduct,Colorcode,Size` 
Can I hide the class so that the combine column appears with the qty column in the datagridview or do I have to do it in the datagridview the visible column becomes false. Please guide from you

Comment: My best suggestion is to hide the columns in the datagrid view.

Comment: `Public Function Getitem() As IEnumerable(Of Stocks) Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Stocks"` if i do in sql dapper is it possible please guide

Comment: I have no idea, I do't even understand the question. It looks like a new question, so you should probably submit it as such.

Comment: I thank you for your perfect answer. I have a new question regarding dapper maybe you can help me. Here My link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76671744/why-datagridview-in-form2-doesnt-appear-population-with-dapper-ms-acess-in-vb-n